# Loop through A table with select case to replace text

Tags: vba, select, replace

I am using MS Access 2010-2013 and I have a update query that replaces a few text with another text. I wanted to convert the query to VBA "Sub Removereplace ()" on my form to loop through possibly a select case for each text in question and replace it if its there. I have no clue how to do this and been trying to find an working example by goggling but no luck. Any ideas? Thanks!!!

```
UPDATE tbl_ImportedTabDelimited SET tbl_ImportedTabDelimited.[Long Description] = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace([Long Description]," ft","'")," in","""")," ""L""",""),",","")
WHERE (((tbl_ImportedTabDelimited.[Long Description]) 
Like "*ft*" Or   (tbl_ImportedTabDelimited.[Long Description]) 
Like "*in*" Or (tbl_ImportedTabDelimited.[Long   Description]) 
Like "*,*" Or (tbl_ImportedTabDelimited.[Long Description]) 
Like "*""L""*"));
```

Comment: What you are suggesting is far slower than doing it in a query.

Comment: Ok, I understand that but I have been trying to figure this out for days so lets just say I want to see how to do it for peace of mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if you really must update things in VBA in a loop:

```
Sub ThisIsABadIdea()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Title, Name, Salary FROM Table1")

    rs.MoveFirst
    While Not rs.EOF
        rs.Edit

        ' Multiple field update
        If Left(rs!Title, 1) = "Z" Then
            rs!Title = "Omega Man"
            rs!Name = "Heston"
            rs!Salary = 15000
        End If

        ' Multiple condition on one field
        Select Case rs!Title
        Case rs!Title = "aa":
            rs!Title = "no way!"
        Case Left(rs!Title, 4) = "xyxy":
            rs!Title = "Double Fem!"
        Case Right(rs!Title, 2) = "-2":
            rs!Title = "It's a dash two experience"
        Case Else
            rs!Title = "It is indescribable"
        End Select

        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: how can I loop more than one (3-4) changes not just one. thanks!